# Length of array in MIPS assembly

Tags: python, arrays, assembly, mips

I have this fragment of code in python:

```
len(the_list)
```

and I want to know how you would translate it to MIPS assembly. "the_list" isn't a list but an array in MIPS

I read up something like

```
lw $t1, ($t2)    #$t2 is where the_list is stored, $t1, is loading the length of the_list
```

is equivalent to the length of the array but it doesn't execute in MIPS.
Any advices about this or am i wrong above?

Comment: You need to store the length yourself, typically by putting a label after your array and subtracting the start (and dividing by item size if needed).

Comment: @Jester so i would create a new label dedicated for storing the length, let's say length:    .word 0. Could you explain a little bit about "subtracting the start"? the one i wrote above, is that representing the length or i would have to do a little bit more? Would love an example since its been only 2 weeks since i starting learning MIPS

Comment: You don't need to declare storage for it, just the label is enough. And subtracting means just that. e.g. `li $t1, end-start`.

Comment: You can create code, which will keep array length as separate value in memory (used often when dynamic arrays are used), but for simple assembly exercises with fixed array you can + should learn how to use Jester's hard-coded length value. But you can create the complex data structures in any way you wish, including storage of length at offset +0 and having the actual values starting at +4, etc... depends on the code you write, how the memory is used.